# ERROR with gradle : The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I am having issues building and testing my React Native app on Android. We updated RN version to 71 recently and I managed to make iOS work but on Android I am stuck with the following error : `The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility` when running any `./gradlew` in the android folder. Even `./gradlew clean` does not work. Syncing gradle in Android Studio return the same error.

I am not using the toolchain functionality nor source and/or target compatibility.

#### build.gradle

```groovy
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply from: "./env.gradle"
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        kotlinVersion = '1.9.0'
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "17.0.0"

        androidXCore = "1.7.0"
        RNMapboxMapsImpl = "mapbox" // required for v10

        RNMapboxMapsLibs = { // optional - only required if you want to customize it
            implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.5.0-beta1'
            implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:5.4.1'
            implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}

def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            // Required for react-native-background-geolocation
            url("${project(':react-native-background-geolocation').projectDir}/libs")
        }
        maven {
            url("${project(':react-native-background-fetch').projectDir}/libs")
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.env.get('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN') ?: ""
            }
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

#### app/build.gradle

```groovy
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
  release: ".env.production",
  staging:".env.staging",
  production:".env.production",
  debug: ".env.staging",
  storybook: ".env.storybook",
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"


import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/@sentry/react-native/sentry.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for in debug.
 */
def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")

android {
    namespace 'com.surlo.surloapp'

    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.22.1"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".staging"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.surlo.surloapp"
        }
        production {}
        storybook {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".staging"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.surlo.surloapp"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.surlo.surloapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        versionName "2.2.19"
        versionCode 111
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
         release {
            storeFile file(project.env.get('UPLOAD_STORE_FILE'))
            storePassword project.env.get('UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD')
            keyAlias project.env.get('UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS')
            keyPassword project.env.get('UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD')
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')

    // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries


    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
      version {
          strictly '1.3.1'
      }
    }
    
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    // implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1"
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.1.0+'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1"


    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

#### Config

```bash
❯ java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)

❯ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.6.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-06-30 15:42:51 UTC
Revision:     dab132169006b16e7ada4ab2456e0c9d6415b52a

Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.11 (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11+9)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "surlomobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "replace": "node ./replace-gradle.js",
    "android": "react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug",
    "android:production": "react-native run-android --variant=productionDebug",
    "build:android:staging": "(cd android && ./gradlew bundleStagingRelease); (yarn android:open:bundle:staging)",
    "android:storybook": "react-native run-android --variant=storybookDebug",
    "build:android:staging:apk": "(cd android && ./gradlew assembleStagingRelease); (yarn android:open:apk)",
    "build:android:production": "(cd android && ./gradlew bundleProductionRelease); (yarn android:open:bundle:production)",
    "build:android:production:apk": "(cd android && ./gradlew assembleProductionRelease); (yarn android:open:apk)",
    "android:clean": "ENVFILE=.env.staging cd android && ./gradlew clean",
    "android:open:bundle:production": "open android/app/build/outputs/bundle/productionRelease",
    "android:open:bundle:staging": "open android/app/build/outputs/bundle/stagingRelease",
    "android:open:apk": "open android/app/build/outputs/apk/production/release",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --scheme 'surloMobile-staging'",
    "ios:production": "react-native run-ios --scheme 'surloMobile'",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "precommit": "yarn lint && yarn tsc",
    "postinstall": "jetify; (cd ios; pod install); exit 0;",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "clean": "npx react-native-clean-project",
    "prestorybook": "rnstl",
    "quality": "yarn lint --fix && yarn tsc -p .",
    "increment-version": "bash scripts/update_version.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.1",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.5.0",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "8.6.0-beta.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.5.1",
    "@react-native/gradle-plugin": "^0.73.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.18",
    "@rematch/core": "^2.2.0",
    "@rematch/loading": "^2.1.2",
    "@rematch/persist": "^2.1.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^5.9.2",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.2.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.11",
    "async-mutex": "^0.4.0",
    "axios": "1.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "camelcase-keys": "^9.0.0",
    "chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.12",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "^11.5.0",
    "expo-location": "^16.3.0",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^7.7.0",
    "i18next": "^23.5.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.45",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-ios": "^4.3.2",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.3.1",
    "luxon": "^3.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "normalize-strings": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.46.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.2.2",
    "react-native": "^0.71.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-background-geolocation": "^4.13.3",
    "react-native-branch": "^5.9.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.71.6",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.11.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient-text": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.9.2",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-storybook-loader": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.14.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "snakecase-keys": "^5.4.7",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.1",
    "@jest/globals": "29.7.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^6.5.6",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds": "^6.5.6",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "^6.5.6",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^6.5.6",
    "@storybook/react-native-server": "^6.5.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.3",
    "@types/camelcase-keys": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/chroma-js": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.199",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.3",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.3",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.3.3",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-derniercri": "https://git@github.com/derniercri/eslint-config-derniercri.git#commit=02fd4c713505902ec314f9d528f03c4327410ae9",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "replace-in-files": "3.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!(@react-native|@react-native-.+|react-native|@react-navigation|react-native-.+|.+/react-native-.+|@sentry|expo-image-manipulator|expo-modules-core|expo-location)/)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@internals/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest-setup/jestGlobalSetup.js"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "babelConfig": true
      },
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/setup-jest"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "react-native-storybook-loader": {
      "searchDir": [
        "./src"
      ],
      "pattern": "**/*.stories.tsx",
      "outputFile": "./storybook/storyLoader.js"
    }
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution to fix the problem and make your app run, but to start with getting rid of that error, check the following file.

> node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\build.gradle.kts

In this file, you will find the `source` and `target`  that you are trying to find.